# ionic/cordova home screen widget (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, widget

I made an android app with ionic.

I want to make a home-screen widget for android.
However, I have no idea how to do this.
I don't care if it is in native android or JAVA.

I have searched for a couple of days but can't find annything.

Can someone help me with setting up the basics or does someone have a tutorial/existing project for me?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Have figured something out? There is Microsoft's project ACE but is abandoned - https://github.com/Microsoft/ace .